# Subclass Cannot be Assigned to Superclass in Firebase DocumentReference with Converter

Tags: typescript, firebase, inheritance, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to have object classes store a reference to their corresponding Firestore `DocumentReference` using a `FirestoreDataConverter`. When I declare the `reference` variable as public, I have no issues. But when I attempt to make it private, the TypeScript linter tells me that the subclass (`Two`) cannot be assigned to the type of the superclass (`One`).

Here's an example...

```js
abstract class One {
    protected reference?: DocumentReference<One>;

    public static converter: FirestoreDataConverter<One>;
}

class Two extends One {
    private reference?: DocumentReference<Two>;

    constructor(reference?: DocumentReference) {
        super();
        this.reference = reference?.withConverter(Two.converter);
    }
}
```

Here's the full error:

```
Property 'reference' in type 'Two' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'One'.
  Type 'DocumentReference<Two> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'DocumentReference<One> | undefined'.
    Type 'DocumentReference<Two>' is not assignable to type 'DocumentReference<One>'.
      Types of property 'converter' are incompatible.
        Type 'FirestoreDataConverter<Two> | null' is not assignable to type 'FirestoreDataConverter<One> | null'.
          Type 'FirestoreDataConverter<Two>' is not assignable to type 'FirestoreDataConverter<One>'.
            The types returned by 'fromFirestore(...)' are incompatible between these types.
              Type 'Two' is not assignable to type 'One'.ts(2416)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with some more options, I realized that the issue was that I was trying to convert the `reference` property from `protected` to `private`. While you can do this normally by re-declaring the property, trying to assign the type to that of the parent class causes an error because it cannot be converted from `protected` to `private`. The *actual* error (which is a TypeScript problem, not a Javascript one, explaining why this was only raised as a warning in the linter) is more visible here:

```js
class One {
    protected reference: TestOne;
}

class Two extends TestOne {
    private reference: TestTwo;
}
```

```
Property 'reference' in type 'Two' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'One'.
  Type 'Two' is not assignable to type 'One'.
    Property 'reference' is private in type 'Two' but not in type 'One'.
```